# My first app appears on Google Play (on my PC) but not on the Play Store from my two 10inch tablets?

Tags: android

Acer with Android 4.0 and Samsung Tab2 with 4.2.

Here is part of my manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

The app works perfectly when transferred to the devices from Eclipse.  Why am I NOT seeing my app on the Play Store on my two tablets???

Any help will be most appreciated since I am at a total loss...Thanks a lot!

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the Country setting of your tablet? Is that exactly where you set the country in your App in google play?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have a `<uses-feature>` in your manifest. This could e.g. be a required front camera, like: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"/>`, which (no?) hardly any tablet has.

Most likely the solution:

```
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" />
```

For reasons unknown!

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct, except for the last sub-clause. Most, if not all, tablets have a front camera. In fact, the only tablet here which doesn't have two cameras is my Nexus 7, and that has a front-camera, but not a back. The most common culprit is the auto-focus requirement, which the Tab2 7" doesn't have.

Comment: That's a great addition, I just kinda assumed based on my own tablet, thanks for the correction

Comment: @user2383919 If that isn't the case could you post your entire manifest file? It's most likely in there the culprit is

Comment: I had to edit my question above or wait for 8 hours to be able to answer my own question!

Comment: Just a guess here, try adding: `<supports-screens 
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" />` --- also, give it 2-3 hours to update the google play store

Comment: Thanks, I will try that tomorrow.  I did check the Android Developer Doc and the android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" is supposed to be sufficient...

Comment: I added android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" and it worked but WHY???  The Android doc says that android:requiresSmallestWidthDp is sufficient, unless I missed something when I read it.  I always want clean code in my programs so does anyone know what is really happening here?

Comment: Google aren't always too into keeping some areas up to date, looks like this is one of them. :-(

Comment: I find it hard to believe Dan.  I bought 4 books on Android programming and none of them covers this.  I am going to start a new thread with that specific question.  I would like to know what's going on before I publish my next app!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is my final and proved solution:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

This is required. And don't forget to set android:xlargeScreens="true", since this is set to false by default, if you don't set it manually. xLargeScreens is required for all screens above 7 inch.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Set your min, and also your targetSdkVersion, while the targetSdkVersion should be set at least to 11 for tablet support.

If you have defined one or more of your activities with the property android:screenOrientation="landscape" or android:screenOrientation="portrait", you'll need the following entries as well:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
```

I've implemented it like that in use of the google play guidelines a few hours ago, and it's working again for all tablets.

Comment: Thanks, I tried android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" and it worked.   But I don't understand why.  The  <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" should be sufficient according to what I read on Google Developer website. I am puzzled...